# How can I select a specific instance of an element inside a DIV using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Let's say that I have the following code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

How would I go about selecting each instance inside of the "container" using CSS without naming it as a class or id or even using style="" on the element itself?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answers below are good. I just came across this article and it might also help.
https://robots.thoughtbot.com/basic-css-selectors-explained-with-cats

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution 1 : Immediate child selector**

You will have to use the CSS selector `>`. This will target all the **immediate** child elements

Example :

```
.className > element {
}
```

See this below:

```css
.container > div {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  margin:10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

**Solution 2 : Nested children selector**

You can  also use it as follows:

```
.className element {
}
```

See this below :

```css
.container div {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

This is slightly different from the previous selector. The difference is that this will select all `divs` (including the nested children) within the `immediate` `divs`. To understand its effect, see below :

```css
.container div {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Solution 3 : Specific child selector (nth-child)**

In case you want to select only a specific/specific set of **immediate** children, you can use the `nth-child selector` as follows:

```
.className > element:nth-child(n) {
}
```

See this below

```css
.container > div {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container > div:nth-child(3n+1) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

**Solution 4 : Nested Specific child selector (nth-child)**

Lastly, you can combine the aforementioned selectors to target specific children and children of children as well as follows :

```
.className > element:nth-child(n) {
}
```

See this below:

```css
.container div {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
}
.container div:nth-child(3n+1) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Among the four solutions listed only one of them is actually correct. I can't in good conscience upvote this answer in spite of the fact that it does provide at least one correct solution, because it's so unnecessarily difficult to find it amongst all the wrong ones.

Comment: @BoltClock Could you explain further on the lines of which do you think is the correct one? Also, why are the other ones wrong? As far as I know (and as shown by the demos themselves), all of these do "target" the containing `divs` without the need of explicitly mentioning an `id` or `class` on them, which by the way, was the original question?

Comment: The question is asking how to select specific instances. Your first two solutions don't select specific instances, they select all children or all descendants. Whether the correct solution is the third or fourth solution depends on the markup - if you're not dealing with any nesting then either is fine.

Comment: Well, @BoltClock, its a case of inference. The question was "How would I go about selecting each instance...". Based on your comment, you **inferred** "The question is asking how to select specific instances". You see, the question doesn't explicitly mention "specific instances". **Yet, you inferred so**. The question is pretty open to interpretation. It may mean selecting each of the instances **OR** specific instances. I hope you understand that if you have the luxury to interpret it one way, so do others have the luxury of interpreting it the other way.

Comment: @BoltClock, Contrary to what you state as *"Among the four solutions listed only one of them is actually correct"*, I have provided solutions which answer **each** (see what each means here) of those two interpretations. None of these solutions is incorrect. Even though you interpreted the question differently, you still did find one solution, right? So, if you do not wish to upvote the answer then please don't, that's fair enough. But please don't comment that they are "wrong" just beacuse they don't "suit" the way you inferred the question.

Comment: "You see, the question doesn't explicitly mention 'specific instances'." It's in the title. I did not infer anything. But I concede that anyone is free to interpret a question however they like.

Answer (score 4):

`nth-of-type(n)` or `nth-child(n)` will work.

See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type)

```css
.container div:nth-of-type(2) {
  /* selects the second one */
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
</div>
```

EDIT: oops! looks like both I and Satwik Nadkarny interpreted your question differently.  It probably would be a good idea to use `>` even in my answer (making it `.container > div:nth-of-type(2)`) to avoid selecting nested divs within the first set.